# Base64 and ROT13 decode in single shell command

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line

I have a string in the following format :

```
(str_rot13(base64_decode("my string")))
```

I am trying to decode it using a single linux command by piping the output of Base64 decode to rot13. 
I am attempting to use `echo 'my string' | base64 --decode` then pipe the output to `tr 'n-za-mN-ZA-M' ‘a-zA-Z’` which applies the Rot13 decode operation on the output.

Can you guide me for the best possible way I can do it using the command line.

***Edit***

Apologies guys, I was looking at the partial script. I just noticed that the complete script is something like this:

```
<?php eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('my string')))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pipe those two commands straight through (the only possible issue I can see are the ‘curly’ quotes in your `tr` command).

### PHP

```
php > echo str_rot13(base64_decode("c2JiCg=="));
foo
```

### Bash

```
echo 'c2JiCg==' | base64 --decode | tr 'n-za-mN-ZA-M' 'a-zA-Z'
foo
```